# Why is my CSS intemittently failing to take effect?

Tags: css, intermittent

I have a problem I see every so often - I create a CSS file, link it in a webpage, but then it sometimes takes effect and sometimes doesn't. I've set up a very simple example which has the problem.

This page is at http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.faces (It's generated from JSF, but I don't think that's relevant - I've copied the HTML source here)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    blah blah...
  </body>
</html>
```

I can view the styles.css file no problem from the browser address bar, at http://localhost:8080/myapp/styles.css

It was working, then after redeploying the app it stopped. Really annoying. I'm using IE7 - can anyone offer any enlightenment on this behaviour?

Comment: Try reloading with Firebug's "net" tab open. It will show you when/if loading the style sheet fails, and show you the error code. You can then go search for that request in your error logs.

Comment: The link for the webpage you have provided runs on your localhost and not available to anybody outside!

Comment: this might be the cause:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
try removing it

Comment: jerjer: that can not be the cause as it doesn't affect the external stylesheet

Comment: Are you saying that the file doesn't load at all, or your changes to the file are not showing?

Comment: define "it stopped". Were no styles applied at all or was it just your changes that weren't being picked up? Try using ctrl+F5 to force a full reload of the page.

Comment: @roryf - no changes we applied at all - Ctrl-F5 - no difference.

Comment: @Pekka - unable to use Firefox (don't ask), @Kangkan yes, it's a local install not a web one. That's why I provided the HTML source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as I ask the question, I work out what's going on!

In this case - something odd has happened, rolling back my JSP file to a previous version - losing the styling attributes. So everything was working fine, but the CSS classes weren't there in the HTML.

Thanks for the help, anyway!